# Counting in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried to make a click counter in MySQL, but it dose not seem to work.

Here's my code in PHP (count.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("myhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydatabase") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`field`) VALUES(\'+1\'); ") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <div onClick="count.php">Click!</div>
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And will this code handle multiple people clicking the button at the same time?

Comment: I think you should use `UPDATE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html . If you use a single `UPDATE` command, it will be always atomic.

Comment: You're adding new rows, all of which contain `+1` - not actually adding (summing) anything. FWIW the code is multiple-user safe as there's no reading of data

Comment: I think UPDATE is just enough. I'm not sure how MySQL handles concurrency, but PostgreSQL should handle multiple clients. I think question is not elaborated and no efforts put into it.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET field = field + 1`

Comment: Multiple people doing the same thing will make it collide, then?

Comment: @user1431627 not in this case - the read and update are happening in the same step (technically the same transaction). If you were to read it into PHP then later do an update, you have a chance for a race condition. By doing it in the same transaction, other updates have to wait until it's finished before they happen

Comment: @Basic But all clicks will be counted, only set on wait?

Comment: @user1431627 yes - technically, if you have millions running at the same time, some might time out - but it's not going to happen unless you're Google

Comment: Haha, well lets not hope so ;) Thank you!

Comment: And for the record here is the code I made for Ajax  pastebin.com/YGUSF2yJ Should it work as good as jQuery's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**onClick** is not like **href**, it shoud look like this:

```
<div onClick="count()">Click</div>
<script>
    function count() {
        // java script function that loads count.php by ajax //
    }
</script>
```

in **count.php** instead of

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (1)");
```

you can use

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = field+1 WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: How do I actually load it by using Ajax. I have heard that I need to cross-reference it because of compatiblity with IE :)

Comment: @user1431627 That's a completely different question. See here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: yeap, i also recommend jQuery for that

Comment: Oh, but I cannot do that. Will you have a look at my code: http://pastebin.com/YGUSF2yJ

This is exactly what jQuery dose, redone by me. (used in another app)

Comment: @user1431627 Well, for a start you're only going to make a request if you're running in IE. Beyond that, it looks approximately correct but if it's a new question, you should ask a new question. Also, you're not providing anywhere near enough information - what doesn't work, why? why can't you use a reliable, tested library?

Answer (score 1):

Put a single row in your table with an Id of (say) `1` and then do....

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `field`=`field`+1 WHERE Id = 1;");
```

This will increment the value.

Comment: Will this collide with other users?

Comment: @user1431627 See my comment on your Q. In short, no

Answer (score 0):

For a single query that does stuff for you:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`Id`, `field`) VALUES (ID_HERE, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field`=`field`+1
```

This will create a new row if the ID doesn't exist yet, or increase the counter if it does.